# see the code of the last successful build in VS 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I need to see the code of the last successful build of my asp.net web page (the one which is shown when you run the code, in a case that the code as some bugs in his current form). how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of a git service. Some are available out of the box in the Team Explorer pane.